# Loading php file with AJAX in Wordpress frontend

Tags: php, ajax

Trying out AJAX request for the first time and facing problem. I want to load a php file on button click in Wordpress site. So far after researching, I got this code:

index.php file:

```
<button id="ajaxbtn">Ajax</button>
<div id="ajax">Some Text</div>
```

ajax.php file (the file i want to be loaded):

```
<?php echo "Hello!" ?>
```

functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){

   wp_localize_script('menu_toggle', 'myajax', 
     array(
       'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
     )
   );  

}

add_action('wp_ajax_tablo', 'tablo');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tablo', 'tablo');

function tablo() {

  // Grab php file output from server
  ob_start();
  include(get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax.php');
  $result['content'] = ob_get_contents(); 
  wp_send_json($result);
}
```

menu_toggle.js file (js file with ajax code):

```
$("#ajaxbtn").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : myajax.ajax_url,
    data : {action: 'tablo'},
    success: function(response) {
      //load the fetched php file into the div
      console.log(response);
      alert(response);
      $('#ajax').append("hello"); 
      $('#ajax').load(response.content);
    }
  });
});
```

I can actually get `alert(response);`which alerts[object Object], and `$('#ajax').append("hello");` displaying, so that means that ajax was connected right way and ajax request is working correctly. But `$('#ajax').load(response.content);` loading the same entire index page in #ajax div instead of loading the content of ajax.php file i actually want. I probably got the wrong code either in `function tablo()` of functions.php file, or in ajax code of menu_toggle.js file. The `console.log(response);` gives crazy amount of output. Can someone please help with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `get_template_part()` function. use ob_end_clean() to Clean the output buffer and turn off output buffering.  I have use `html()` to append data  `jQuery('#ajax').html(response.content);`. I have tested and working fine for me.

jquery :

```
jQuery("#ajaxbtn").click(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      dataType : 'json',
      url : myajax.ajax_url,
      data : {action: 'tablo'},
      success: function(response) {
        jQuery('#ajax').html(response.content);
      }
    });
  });
```

ajax function :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_tablo', 'tablo');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tablo', 'tablo');
function tablo() {
  // Grab php file output from server
  ob_start();
  get_template_part( 'ajax' );
  $result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $return = array('content' => $result);
  wp_send_json($return);
  wp_die();
}
```

Comment: works perfect! thank you very much